dvd rip only finds first episode of 5 in dvd
I have a DVD which contains 3 up to 5 episodes I want to rip for safekeeping.
I can play the whole DVD with vlc, but if I try to rip it with either handbrake (1.5.1 (x86_64)) or vlc (3.0.16) I can only rip the first episode and not the others.
Do you have any hints how I can get to the other episodes?
I am using kubuntu 22.4 64bit with a blue ray drive.
P.S.: also copying the dvd with k3b is no problem
